# Where do Azure WebJobs read configuration settings from?

Tags: azure, configuration-files, azure-webjobs, appsettings, azure-webjobssdk

I’m developing an Azure WebJob with Visual Studio 2019, with Microsoft.NETCore.App v5.0.0 framework. I need to read values from configuration, but I don’t understand where I should put them to finally overwrite them in the Azure WebJob’s page in the Azure portal. So far, I’ve created the following `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "..."
  },
  "firstValue": "...",
  "secondValue": "..."
}
```

The following public method

```
public static async Task Example(
   [BlobTrigger("%firstValue%/{blobName}")] Stream blobReceived
   [Blob("%secondValue%/{blobName}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream blobToWrite,
   ILogger logger)
```

Correctly reads the values of `firstValue` and `secondValue` from `appsettings.json`. That said, I see other projects that use `app.config` files, whose values are then retrieved with something like:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["..."];
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["..."].ConnectionString;
```

Should I use `app.config` instead of `appsettings.json`? How do I read values I put in the `appsettings.json` file when we speak about Azure WebJobs?

Comment: app.config if for .net framework apps. appsettings is for .net core apps.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio thanks. How can I read values from `appsettings.json`? As you can see, `firstValue` and `secondValue` are read with the `%...%` syntax because that is the special syntax for attributes, as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot access the app settings from Azure WebJobs directly**, but you could consider using rest API to access the AppSettings in the Azure portal.

Actually, WebJobs are console app, which uses the environment variables stored in the system, which is different from the AppSettings in the Azure portal. AppSettings stored in IIS can only be invoked from this specific web app.